# Running ECL from Visual Studio Code with no local repo

Tags: hpcc-ecl

We have a HPCC Cluster that is connected to a Git Repository.

Is there any way to bypass a local compile when invoking ECL code from VSC?

This is a use case where teams of individuals will need to run ECL 'templates' -  where filter conditions will change. Ideally want to avoid the team needing to clone the repo and look at regular pulls to stay in sync.

I know the Playground can be used to run code against the remote code but is not ideal for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the Client Tools PDF:

> *HPCC Systems integrates native support for leveraging Git.
> The `--main` option has been extended to support compiling a query directly from a Git repository. When invoked, it retrieves the ECL code specified from the Git repository, compiles the code, and runs the query. The checkout is done on the remote ECLCCServer rather than on the client machine.*

So in your VS-Code `Settings.json` file, add the following:

```
ecl.eclccArgs: ["--main"]
```

You may also need to set:

```
ecl.eclccSyntaxArgs: ["--main"]
```

Hope this helps!

Bob